# iPhone 4.3.3 shows wrong(depreciated) 'zoom-in' snapshot(screenshot) at launch

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

It's hard to describe my iPhone's situation..

I launched an App and used it. for example, a Twitter app.

After that I closed it with Home Button.

Then I launched a few apps which were enough to take most memory.

And, when I launch the Twitter app again, a screenshot(snapshot), which was taken exactly when I closed the app at first, was shown about 0.5~1 sec.

I know this is a way of animation effect, but mine is somewhat wrong, 
because that screenshot should be 'loading image (ex: Default.png)' if the app launched long time ago is about to start from the beginning (the 'twitter' app must be closed because of out of memory).

It makes stressful situation when I use kind of 'personal memo app'.
Before I upgrade to iOS 4.3.3, whenever I launch this app, it requires password without showing any old screenshot.
But now, everyone can see my memo because of that automatic snapshot which pops up about a second.

Help needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your app goes into background you need to hide/remove all the views you don't want to appear when you open the app again.

You should do this in the [`applicationDidEnterBackground:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) UIApplicationDelegate method.

See the **Remove sensitive information from views before moving to the background** bullet point in [this section of the Apple Developer Docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW47)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to prevent that is to set "Application does not run in background" in your plist file.